# Communication between different instances of same fragment with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout with ViewPager to show tabs in my app. I have only two tabs. These two tabs uses the same fragment (different instances) and I have one recycler in each fragment. Every recycler shows different data.

In my `FragmentPagerAdapter`, I do this:

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if (position == 0) {
            bundle.putString(TreinamentosFragment.EXTRA_TIPO, TreinamentosFragment.TIPO_PENDENTE);
        } else {
            bundle.putString(TreinamentosFragment.EXTRA_TIPO, TreinamentosFragment.TIPO_CONCLUIDO);
        }

        Fragment fragment = new TreinamentosFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

With that approach I'm able to know at runtime what type is every fragment 
and Get the correct informations in web service to show.

But, the problem is, when user is in Fragment A and interact in some way with one of the recycler items, I remove this item from the adapter and I need to put this item in the adapter of Fragment B. How can I do this? How can I recover the specific instance of Fragment B and change its adapter?

I wanna to do this without use of no kind of event bus.

My Fragment A and B are already inside another fragment because I'm using Navigation Drawer too.

Comment: setTag and findFragmentBytag.

Comment: I guess you can use interfaces and set up callback methods to handle this.

Comment: @tinysunlight where can I set the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TreinamentosFragment extends Fragment{


   public onItemClick(Item item){

      List fragments =  getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
      for(Fragment fragment : fragments ){
          if(fragment  instanceof TreinamentosFragment  &&TreinamentosFragment.TIPO_CONCLUIDO .equalIgnoreCase(fragment.getArgments().getString(TreinamentosFragment.EXTRA_TIPO))){
            (TreinamentosFragment )fragment.addItem(item);
         }
      }
      //or
      List fragmentA =  getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().FindFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":1");
      if(fragmentA instanceof TreinamentosFragment){
         (TreinamentosFragment )fragmentA.addItem(item);
      }

   }

   public addItem(Item item){

   }
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use EventBus.

Comment: I change the implementation for LocalBroadcastManager. Much more elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Singleton data classes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

You have 2 adapters then you need two Singleton Data classes.. When you delete item from Fragment-A then add that deleted item in Frag-B`s Singleton Data instance. As Fragment-B resume/visible the just reload data from Frag-B`s Singleton Data instance.

No event Bus solutions.. :)

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static volatile SingletonDemo instance = null;
    private SingletonDemo() { }

    public static synchronized SingletonDemo getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonDemo();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I can use only one Singleton Data Instance, for fragment B. But, I don't get how to this... I need to have the list of data in that Singleton Class? The same I use in the adapter, right?

Comment: Singleton data class has only one instance in whole application once created. so, you need a method to get that single instance .. more you can read the wiki link for knowledge .. or tell me what are your data type ... i will write one for you..   user getInstance() for auto create or already created instance